# SQL: UPDATE TOP 3 wouldn't work?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

I have this `table1` and I want to update `3` of it where `owner=0`

now I've come cross TOP (number) but i doesn't seems to work out. tried `TOP 3` tried `TOP (3)` here my line of code:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE TOP 3 table1 SET owner=1 WHERE owner=0") or die("can't update");
```

result : `can't update`.

I tried top with `SELECT`. here:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table1 WHERE owner=1") or die("can't select");
```

result: `can't select`.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: [The `TOP` keyword is for SQL Server and MS Access](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp). From the looks of it, you're using a MySQL database. Try the `LIMIT` keyword instead.

Comment: Looks like you are using `Mysql`. In Mysql, `Limit` is used to restrict the result. `UPDATE table1 SET owner=1 WHERE owner=0 LIMIT 3`

Comment: Using `top` or `limit` without an order by clause is likely to lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top` is part of Microsoft's [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) specific syntax. [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), which you are using, is a different RDBMS, and does not support this syntax. Instead, you can use the `limit` syntax, both in a `select` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE owner = 1 LIMIT 3
```

Or an update statement:

```
UPDATE table1 SET owner = 1 WHERE owner = 0 LIMIT 3
```